# AnyLogic: How to find a maximum value of a collection

Tags: java, anylogic

In my model I have a collection with values of temperatures and I want to find the maximum value with a function. I have found the following function:

`double max( collection, value )` - Returns maximum value in the given collection.

If I use this function for my collection "temperatures" it doesnt work:

> double max(temperatues,result);

Do I have to use a class for this kind of problem? I am a real Java-beginner and very desperate. Can someone give me an advise?

Comment: Show us the code to your method

Comment: Well how would you do this by hand? Come up with a method with a simple pencil and paper and then translate that to code

Comment: *"it doesnt work"* is not an error description. What doesn't work? What are the values you use, what is the result you get, and what result would you expect instead? Also please add your code. See [MCVE] for help.

Comment: what did you do till now? post some code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `double result = Collections.max(temperatures);` or `double result = temperatures.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).max();`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
double result = max(temperatures,t->t.doubleValue());
```